# Finding Probability Using Sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How do I go about solving the following probability problem.

$P(A\cup(B^{\complement}\cup C^{\complement})^{\complement})$.

Events $A$, $B$ and $C$ are disjoint and $P(A)=2/5$

Using De Morgan's for
$B^{\complement}\cup C^{\complement}=(B\cap C)^{\complement}$

and the compliment of this gives

$B\cap C$.

So do I end up with

$A\cup (B\cap C)$

If $P(A)=2/5$. How do I find the propability of

$A\cup(B^{\complement}\cup C^{\complement})^{\complement}$

Comment: Note $\cup$ turns to $\cap$ in De Morgan: $ B^\complement \cup C^\complement = (B \ {\color{red}\cap} \ C)^\complement $

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I corrected the question.

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are disjoint, then $B \cap C $ is empty, and hence $A\cup (B\cap C) = A$.

Comment: @rizzo Before asking any new questions first take a look at  [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you Hayk. And thanks for the link drhab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the sets $A,B,C$ are disjoint we have:$$P(A\cup (B^{\complement}\cup C^{\complement})^{\complement})=P(A\cup (B\cap C))=P(A)+P(B\cap C)=P(A)+P(\varnothing)=\frac25+0=\frac25$$